# Operation Queue not executing in order even after setting priority and dependency on Operations

Tags: ios, swift, queue, nsoperationqueue

I am making three api calls and want that API1 should execute first, once completed API2 should execute followed by API3.
I used operation queue for this with adding dependency over operations. I tried setting priority as well but not getting api calls in order. Help me out how to make it properly.

Code is like this :

```
let op1 = Operation()
op1.completionBlock = {
    self.APICall(urlString: self.url1)
}
op1.queuePriority = .veryHigh

let op2 = Operation()
op2.completionBlock = {
    self.APICall(urlString: self.url2)
}
op2.queuePriority = .high

let op3 = Operation()
op3.completionBlock = {
    self.APICall(urlString: self.url3)
}

op3.queuePriority = .normal

op2.addDependency(op1)
op3.addDependency(op2)

queue.addOperations([op1, op2, op3], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

I put the API Call Method in DispatchQueue.main.sync like this:

```
func APICall(urlString: String) {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "text/html"
    ]
    print(urlString)
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {

        Alamofire.request(urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
            response in
            // self.stopActivityIndicator()
            print(response.result.value)
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                break
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the code in each of your completion blocks is asynchronous so the blocks complete immediately.

Comment: @rmaddy I was trying to set asynchronous to false, but on queue "isasynchronous" is a get only property. Can u suggest how to set it synchronous?

Comment: It's the `APICall` method that is asynchronous. Nothing you do to the operations will change that fact.

Comment: @rmaddy  I put the API Call method in Dispatch Queue Sync block but still getting unordered result. pls check the updated question details.

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56003965/2545465 I have used semaphores

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Thanks Sequence order is working. But I used OperationsQueue because I want to cancel all ongoing operations on button click and make api call's again for different date. With dispatchQueue i am not able to cancel the ongoing operations. Could u suggest how to do it.

Comment: @ShivamTripathi would you pls try setting `queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` and check if it works?

Comment: @PiyushPatel i used the answer provided by Rajan. But in that case i am not able to cancel ongoing operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. If you’re trying to manage dependencies between operations, you cannot use the operation’s `completionBlock` for the code that the dependencies rely upon. The completion block isn't called until after the operation is complete (and thus defeating the purpose of any dependencies).

   So the following will *not* work as intended:

   ```
   let queue = OperationQueue()

   let op1 = Operation()
   op1.completionBlock = {
       print("starting op1")
       Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
       print("finishing op1")
   }

   let op2 = Operation()
   op2.completionBlock = {
       print("starting op2")
       Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
       print("finishing op2")
   }

   op2.addDependency(op1)

   queue.addOperations([op1, op2], waitUntilFinished: false)
   ```

   But if you define the operations like so, it will work:

   ```
   let op1 = BlockOperation() {
       print("starting op1")
       Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
       print("finishing op1")
   }

   let op2 = BlockOperation {
       print("starting op2")
       Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
       print("finishing op2")
   }
   ```

   (But this only works because I redefined operations that were synchronous. See point 3 below.)

   It’s worth noting generally you never use `Operation` directly. As the [docs say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation):

   > An abstract class that represents the code and data associated with a single task. ...
   >
   > Because the `Operation` class is an abstract class, you do not use it directly but instead subclass or use one of the system-defined subclasses ([`NSInvocationOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsinvocationoperation) or [`BlockOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/blockoperation)) to perform the actual task.

   Hence the use of `BlockOperation`, above, or subclassing it as shown below in point 3.
2. One should not use priorities to manage the order that operations execute if the order must be strictly honored. As the `queuePriority` [docs say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1411204-queuepriority) (emphasis added):

   > This value is used to *influence* the order in which operations are dequeued and executed...
   >
   > You should use priority values only as needed to classify the relative priority of non-dependent operations. Priority values should not be used to implement dependency management among different operation objects. If you need to establish dependencies between operations, use the `addDependency(_:)` method instead.

   So, if you queue 100 high priority operations and 100 default priority operations, you are *not* guaranteed that all of the high priority ones will start before the lower priority ones start running. It will tend to prioritize them, but not strictly so.
3. The first point is moot, as you are calling asynchronous methods. So you can’t use simple `Operation` or `BlockOperation`. If you don’t want a subsequent network request to start until the prior one finishes, you’ll want to wrap these network request in custom asynchronous `Operation` subclass with all of the special KVO that entails:

   ```
   class NetworkOperation: AsynchronousOperation {
       var request: DataRequest

       static var sessionManager: SessionManager = {
           let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: .default)
           manager.startRequestsImmediately = false
           return manager
       }()

       init(urlString: String, parameters: [String: String]? = nil, completion: @escaping (Result<Any>) -> Void) {
           let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
               "Accept": "text/html"
           ]

           let string = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
           let url = URL(string: string)!
           request = NetworkOperation.sessionManager.request(url, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)

           super.init()

           request.responseJSON { [weak self] response in
               completion(response.result)
               self?.finish()
           }
       }

       override func main() {
           request.resume()
       }

       override func cancel() {
           request.cancel()
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can do:

   ```
   let queue = OperationQueue()

   let op1 = NetworkOperation(urlString: ...) { result in
       ...
   }

   let op2 = NetworkOperation(urlString: ...) { result in
       ...
   }

   let op3 = NetworkOperation(urlString: ...) { result in
       ...
   }

   op2.addDependency(op1)
   op3.addDependency(op2)

   queue.addOperations([op1, op2, op3], waitUntilFinished: false)
   ```

   And because that’s using `AsynchronousOperation` subclass (shown below), the operations won’t complete until the asynchronous request is done.

   ```
   /// Asynchronous operation base class
   ///
   /// This is abstract to class performs all of the necessary KVN of `isFinished` and
   /// `isExecuting` for a concurrent `Operation` subclass. You can subclass this and
   /// implement asynchronous operations. All you must do is:
   ///
   /// - override `main()` with the tasks that initiate the asynchronous task;
   ///
   /// - call `completeOperation()` function when the asynchronous task is done;
   ///
   /// - optionally, periodically check `self.cancelled` status, performing any clean-up
   ///   necessary and then ensuring that `finish()` is called; or
   ///   override `cancel` method, calling `super.cancel()` and then cleaning-up
   ///   and ensuring `finish()` is called.

   public class AsynchronousOperation: Operation {

       /// State for this operation.

       @objc private enum OperationState: Int {
           case ready
           case executing
           case finished
       }

       /// Concurrent queue for synchronizing access to `state`.

       private let stateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".rw.state", attributes: .concurrent)

       /// Private backing stored property for `state`.

       private var _state: OperationState = .ready

       /// The state of the operation

       @objc private dynamic var state: OperationState {
           get { stateQueue.sync { _state } }
           set { stateQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) { _state = newValue } }
       }

       // MARK: - Various `Operation` properties

       open         override var isReady:        Bool { return state == .ready && super.isReady }
       public final override var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }
       public final override var isExecuting:    Bool { return state == .executing }
       public final override var isFinished:     Bool { return state == .finished }

       // KVN for dependent properties

       open override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
           if ["isReady", "isFinished", "isExecuting"].contains(key) {
               return [#keyPath(state)]
           }

           return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
       }

       // Start

       public final override func start() {
           if isCancelled {
               state = .finished
               return
           }

           state = .executing

           main()
       }

       /// Subclasses must implement this to perform their work and they must not call `super`. The default implementation of this function throws an exception.

       open override func main() {
           fatalError("Subclasses must implement `main`.")
       }

       /// Call this function to finish an operation that is currently executing

       public final func finish() {
           if !isFinished { state = .finished }
       }
   }
   ```
4. As very minor observation, your code specified GET request with JSON parameters. That doesn’t make sense. GET requests have no body in which JSON could be included. GET requests only use URL encoding. Besides you’re not passing any parameters.